# Windows 10 Explorer path max. characters (Other solutions on stack overflow don't work)

Tags: path, windows-10, explorer

I have a problem. I recently updated to Windows 10.
A few days ago I recognized, that if I open a path that has more than 256 chracters it crashes.

I searched a lot in the internet for solutions and I tried a few.

I tried to fix this with gpedit.msc where I can activate the longer win32 paths. Even after a restart, it didn't worked.

I also tried it with regedit. But it didn't work either.

My Windows Version:

Windows 10 Pro (1607) 64bit

Does somebody have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support.

Comment: I've already answered it on superuser.com: http://superuser.com/a/1114683/174557. Explorer is not ready to fully support long paths

Answer (score -1):

Make sure "Always show icons, never thumbnails" is checked under Folder Options in File Explorer.

Answer (score -2):

256 is the historic max length for a file path on Windows. There is no way to guarantee that paths longer than this will work with all programs. Lots has apparently been done to improve this in recent versions of Windows and with tooling but there's nothing you can do to force everything to work with longer path names. :(

Comment: with V1607, MS "fixed" that limit (http://stackoverflow.com/a/27694470/1466046) but it requires a GPO setting and the app must have an entry in the manifest file.