# Is there any difference between FILENAME_MAX and PATH_MAX in C?

Tags: c

What gets me really confused is some programmers refer to the filename as what I refer to the path, eg. `/Users/example/Desktop/file.txt`. What I call the file *name* would just be `file.txt`, but apparently some people refer to the *path* `/Users/example/Desktop/file.txt` as the *filename*. This gets me really confused. That being said, are macros `FILENAME_MAX` and `PATH_MAX` the same?

`FILENAME_MAX` is defined in `stdio.h` or something so it's cross platform, but am I giving my self extra work doing this?

```
#ifdef __linux__
#   include <linux/limits.h>
#elif defined(_WIN32)
#   include <windows.h>
#   define PATH_MAX MAX_PATH
#else
#   include <sys/syslimits.h>
#endif
```

When just `#include <stdio.h>` and using `FILENAME_MAX` is enough? To create path buffers large enough to hold *any* file path?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Limits-for-Files.html

Comment: > Usage Note: Don’t use FILENAME_MAX as the size of an array in which to store a file name! You can’t possibly make an array that big!

Comment: But on mac it's only 1024

Comment: @userrandomnumbers If you're going to trust that it's 1024 then don't use the constant, hard code it. The point of using the constant is that the value can be different.

Comment: To be portable, stay below those limits when creating files, but don't depend on files created by others to respects those limits.

Answer (score 4):

***tl;dr Don't trust either of them.***

A "path" is an absolute path like `/home/you/foo.txt` or a relative path like `you/foo.txt` or even `foo.txt`.

A "filename" is poorly defined. It could be just the "basename" `foo.txt` or it could be a synonym for "path". The C standard seems to use "filename" to mean "path". For example, `fopen` takes a `filename` which is really a path.

## FILENAME_MAX is standard C, PATH_MAX is POSIX, MAX_PATH is Windows.

`FILENAME_MAX` is a C standard constant...

> which  expands  to  an  integer  constant  expression  that  is  the  size  needed  for  an  array  of char large  enough  to  hold  ***the  longest  file  name  string  that  the  implementation guarantees can be opened.***

`PATH_MAX` is not part of the C standard. It is a [POSIX constant](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/limits.h.html)...

> Maximum number of bytes in a pathname, including the terminating null character.

If the path is too long, POSIX functions should give an `ENAMETOOLONG` error, but not all compilers enforce this.

`MAX_PATH` is a [Windows API constant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation)...

> In the Windows API (with some exceptions discussed in the following paragraphs), the maximum length for a path is MAX_PATH, which is defined as 260 characters. A local path is structured in the following order: drive letter, colon, backslash, name components separated by backslashes, and a terminating null character. For example, the maximum path on drive D is "D:\some 256-character path string"

For example, C standard `fopen` uses FILENAME_MAX. POSIX [`open`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) uses `PATH_MAX`.

## But probably don't trust them.

`FILENAME_MAX` is not safe to use to allocate memory because it might be `INT_MAX`. The GCC documentation warns...

> Unlike PATH_MAX, this macro is defined even if there is no actual limit imposed. In such a case, its value is typically a very large number. This is always the case on GNU/Hurd systems.
>
> Usage Note: Don’t use FILENAME_MAX as the size of an array in which to
> store a file name! You can’t possibly make an array that big! Use
> dynamic allocation (see Memory Allocation) instead.

`PATH_MAX` may not be defined.

Because they are hard coded by the *operating system*, neither can be trusted to be a true representation of what the *file system* can handle. For example, my Mac defines both PATH_MAX and FILENAME_MAX as 1024. A FAT32 filesystem has a limit of 255 characters. If I mount a FAT32 filesystem on my Mac, PATH_MAX and FILENAME_MAX will be incorrect.

[Evan Klitzke describes the problems with PATH_MAX](https://eklitzke.org/path-max-is-tricky) and by extension FILENAME_MAX.

If a function requires you to allocate a buffer to store a path, there is often an alternative which will allocate memory for you, or which will take a max size. If you're left with no choice, 1024 or 4096 are good choices.

Comment: Probably if you mount a msdos filesystem in your mac, you'll be able to create paths larger than 255characters.  The problem is that later, you'll have files in your dos filesystem that cannot be opened from ms-dos.  The `PATH_MAX` limit is the limit imposed by the system call subsystem to system calls that deal with path names.  It doesn't depend on the filesystem (except if the filesystem itself has a more stringent limit)  It's there only to protect the kernel memory from abuses, as the kernel needs to copyin all the file path in order to parse the filename.

Answer (score 3):

It is often (quite arbitrarily) set so `PATH_MAX` equals `4096` and `NAME_MAX` (`FILENAME_MAX`?) would be `255`, [as mentioned here](https://serverfault.com/questions/9546/filename-length-limits-on-linux).

This should be considered legacy in practice due to possible some file names could end up being longer than `PATH_MAX` / `FILENAME_MAX` due to different ways path name lengths, path name concatenation and path name expansion could be performed (not to mention differences in string encodings).

In addition, sometimes the defined `PATH_MAX` value has little or nothing to do with actual limits (if any) imposed by the OS.

For a long time (maybe still), Windows systems defined `PATH_MAX` as `260`, while the OS supported path names up to 32Kb or more (there are [some details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation)).

Comment: 4096 is not selected arbitrarily. Most probably, as it is the length of a virtual page the kernel allocates a single page to store it, and so it has a simpler structure to manage. A page is an unit of measuring memory that the kernel uses frequently for possibly large (but not too much) structures, and it can be swapped out if the kernel needs space for higher performance things.

Comment: @LuisColorado - that you. I understand the reason for this somewhat arbitrary choice and its historical roots. But by now one might argue that kernel page sizes are irrelevant. Moreover, [the 4096Kb page size is arguably obsolete](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.154.2023) (though I might as well be standardized, seeing as how much we rely on it).

Comment: yeah... of course... and the `openat(2)` is also there for something.  If someone modifies the kernel to allow arbitrary long filenames to the kernel, a malicious user can dedicate his time to try to open files whose names are several gigabytes long, and the kernel might have to expect to have this amount of nonswappable memory to hold the full filename. Just oversimplify things, that the kernel developers will solve all and every problem that comes from this.

Answer (score 1):

These aren't comparable at all. The *nix constant `PATH_MAX` is the largest path you can pass to a system call on *nix operating systems but longer paths can exist because system calls take relative paths, while the Windows constant `MAX_PATH` was the largest possible absolute path that could occur on Windows. In fact `MAX_PATH` has been revoked by the ABI but you need to [opt-in](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27680647/14768) to using longer paths.

Comment: I'm afraid not, @joshua.  `MAX_PATH` is the maximum path you can pass to the kernel in a system call.  To support longer paths (which is perfectly possible) you need to: 1) use system calls as `openat(2)` etc. or 2) change your current directory to a subdirectory and use relative paths.

Comment: @LuisColorado: ? The stuff about MAX_PATH is from Windows, where openat() doesn't exist.

Comment: windows has a limited max path... what I said is not applicable to windows. Your answer doesn't make any assumption, and, as the constant is defined in POSIX, I'm afraid Windows is not an option here.  There's no need to use `openat(2)` to access deeper paths, you can use `chdir(2)` and then access the file using a relative path.  See my answer, and you'll get there how to do it.

Comment: @LuisColorado: I made some minor wording changes but I think you've got your constant names backwards. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file

Comment: Joshua, the question makes absolutely no reference to Windows or non POSIX systems at all.  Probably `openat()` is not available in windows.... but once it wasn't also in unix but the problem predates that system call. Paths are unlimited length, by their definition, but the kernel needs to impose a maximum length to the amount of path you can give to it when `open()`/`create()`/`unlink()`/`stat()`/etc.  I don't remember the last time I used MAX_PATH for something, but I use to do the exercises proposed in my answer to unix students, and you seem not have read my answer at all.

Comment: @LuisColorado: Sure does. "cross platform" and `#elif defined(_WIN32)`

Comment: Nope, it also has an `#ifdef __linux__` in the top.... He is trying to compile/modify a portable program that has different includes for different platforms.  There's nothing in his question that states he is using a windows environment.  The question asks for the difference between `FILENAME_MAX` and `MAX_PATH`, and not between `MAX_PATH` and `PATH_MAX`.  Why do you suspect that the PO is using Windows at all?

Comment: I can show you hundreds of linux programs that have those same lines and are not cross compiled, but to port them to windows.

Answer (score 1):

`PATH_MAX` is normally a fixed constant (for posix systems) that specify the maximum length of the path parameter you pass to the kernel in a system call (e.g. `open(2)` syscall)

But the maximum path length a file can have, is not affected by this constant, as you can test with this simple shell scritp:

```
$ i=0
> while [ "$i" -lt 2000 ]
> do mkdir "$i"
>    cd "$i"
>    i=`expr "$i" + 1`
> done
$ pwd
/home/lcu/0/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/[intermediate output not shown...]/1996/1997/1998/1999
```

Now, if you try:

```
$ cd `pwd`
-bash: cd: /home/lcu/0/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/[intermediate output not shown...]/1996/1997/1998/1999: File name too long
```

Showing you that the problem is when bash tries to do the `chdir(2)` system call. (there's a little routine below that shows you how to open a file whose name is longer than the `PATH_MAX` constant)

You will end in a directory that has many more characters in it's name than the `PATH_MAX` constant.
That doesn't mean you cannot access that file from the root directory, but you have to do it

- changing your curren directory (as the script does)
- using the `openat(2)` and friends to use a *closer* opend directory as start point to access it.
  The absolute number of path elements a file can have to the root node is limited only by the number of inodes in the filesystem, and the total capacity of it.

## Edit

> When just #include <stdio.h> and using FILENAME_MAX is enough? To create path buffers large enough to hold any file path?

The only way to support *any* file length, for opening a file in a POSIX operating system and be portable at the same time, is to divide your path in short enough chunks of path, and do `n-1` `chdir(2)` to the actual place you have your files on.  Then call your `open(2)` system call with the last chunk, and then return to the directory you where, if that's possible, with the `fchdir(2)` system call (if your system has it).  In case you have the `openat(2)` system call, you can just open the directories (with the `opendir()` call) closing the previous (as you only use it to open the next dir) and to get close enough to the final directory to be able to open it with an `openat(2)` system call.

Below is a (work in progress) `myfopen()` call that tries to open a file longer thatn the `PATH_MAX` limit, from `<limits.h>`:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "myfopen.h"

FILE *my_fopen(const char *filename, const char *mode)
{
    if (strlen(filename) > PATH_MAX) {
        char *work_name = strdup(filename);
        if (!work_name) {
            return NULL; /* cannot malloc */
        }
        char *to_free   = work_name;  /* to free at end */
        int dir_fd      = -1;
        while(strlen(work_name) >= PATH_MAX) {
            char *p = work_name + PATH_MAX - 1;
            while(*p != '/') p--;
            /* p points to the previous '/' to the PATH_MAX limit */
            *p++ = '\0';
            if (dir_fd < 0) {
                dir_fd = open(work_name, 0);
                if (dir_fd < 0) {
                    ERR("open: %s: %s\n", work_name,
                            strerror(errno));
                    free(to_free);
                    return NULL;
                }
            } else {
                int aux_fd = openat(dir_fd, work_name, 0);
                close(dir_fd);
                if (aux_fd < 0) {
                    ERR("openat: %s: %s\n", work_name,
                        strerror(errno));
                    free(to_free);
                    return NULL;
                }
                dir_fd = aux_fd;
            }
            work_name = p;
        }
        /* strlen(work_name) < PATH_MAX,
         * work_name points to the last chunk and
         * dir_fd is the directory to base the real fopen
         */
        int fd = openat(
                dir_fd,
                work_name,
                O_RDONLY); /* this needs to be
                            * adjusted, based on what is
                            * specified in string mode */
        close(dir_fd);
        if (fd < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "openat: %s: %s\n",
                    work_name, strerror(errno));
            free(to_free);
            return NULL;
        }
        free(to_free);
        return fdopen(fd, mode);
    }
    return fopen(filename, mode);
}
```

(you will need to work the appropiate set of bit masks to pass to the final `openat()` call, in order to comply with the different ways of specifying the open mode of the `fopen()` vs. `open()` calls)

The basic problem with the maximum file name length (which is, why the kernel designers don't support an unbounded buffer to hold the full name of the file) is a security based one.  If you allow a user to pass a 20Gb long filename into kernel space, probably you'll run out kernel memory space and that cannot be permitted (there should be a strong weakness in the system, as a malicious user could block the whole kernel, just passing a very long filename)

In the normal case, I have never had to deal with files longer than 1024 bytes, except for demostrations of this specific problem, so IMHO you should accept that limit, and procure to use short filenames (shorter than 1024 is a good limit)

On other side, you are mentioning many constants here:

- `FILENAME_MAX` is used by stdio system, but its value is to be used only with stdio routines.  Its documentation states that:

> This macro constant expands to an integral expression corresponding to the size needed for an array of char elements to hold the longest file name string allowed by the library. Or, if the library imposes no such restriction, it is set to the recommended size for character arrays intended to hold a file name.

This means that it's a secure length you can tie to in order to be able to call `fopen(3)` and pass it a working filename.

- `PATH_MAX` is a secure value that you can use on your system probably.  If you try to open files (with the `open(2)` system call) or to erase (`unlink(2)`), rename, etc.  Probably you'll run in trouble if you try to do so with filenames longer than this.

The limitation on the file path length comes from a limitation imposed by the system call subsystem, and not from the filesystem involved on the operation, so normally the limitation will be for all files in the system, and not for a specific mounted filesystems (which can be further limited, or not)

In my opinion, the limits are well thought, and using the values published will be ok for the majority of cases.  And no tool in the operating system allows you to open a file with a path longer than `PATH_MAX`.