# Allow long paths in windows 11 - not working

Tags: windows

I am working on windows 11 and using GIT. I have failed to checkout a branch due to some of the files turned to be in a too-long path.

I followed the two suggestions how to allow long paths in windows (as described [here](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-enable-or-disable-win32-long-paths-in-windows-11-10). and also same solution in SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27680647/does-max-path-issue-still-exists-in-windows-10?rq=4)) I did restart and still nothing helps. I still can't checkout due to this problem.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

That was quick:
eventually what solved the problem for me was adding this configuration in git:

```
git config --system core.longpaths true
```

(Following the solution discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575662/filename-too-long-in-git-for-windows?rq=2))