# Visual Studio 2012 Integration with Git Plugin

Tags: git, github

I have tried to configure GitHub with Visual Studio 2012 update 4. I get the following error message:

> An error occurred. Detailed message: An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Os (Error).Could not open `C:/Auto/Automation/Automation/DevAutomation/............/........./......../....../...../........./TestSuite/.../OrderSuite/OrderTestParent/ScenarioLibrary/content.txt` for writing: The data area passed to a system call is too small.

When I run the command below in Git bash (GIT Client)(following the advice from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26111092/1288760)), it works fine:

```
$ git config --system core.longpaths true
```

But when I tried to clone the Visual Studio 2012 with Git HUB, I'm encountering the same issue. I searched for similar problems and the [solution given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21123415/git-pull-aborted-with-error-filename-too-long) is to edit directly your `.git/config` file:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    (...)
    longpaths = true        <-- (add this line under core section)
```

To conclude, I have added the below in the `.gitattributes` file in Visual Studio Team Explorer (*Home > Settings > Git Settings*).

```
[core]
* longpaths = true
```

But still didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As you are getting over the MAX_PATH length, try moving the whole project to a different location (with shorter path).